# Meteor build with shrinkwrap

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor, build, shrinkwrap

I am trying to build and deploy a Meteor project. My constraint is that I have to deploy the app on a remote computer of my local network without internet, so the npm install should not need to connect anywhere.

My idea is to use shrinkwrap and shrinkpack as described here:
https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#npm-shrinkpack

Then build as described here:
https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild

What I do on the dev box:

```
    meteor npm shrinkwrap // this properly updates the npm-shrinkwrap.json
    meteor npm shrinkpack // this properly populates the \node_shrinkwrap folder with the tars of the dependencies
    meteor --production
    //terminate meteor 
    meteor build ..\build // I cannot find the tars for the dependencies in the output
```

Then I copy the tarball to the remote computer:

```
   tar -zxf coolMeteorAngular2App.tar.gz
   cd bundle\programs\server
   npm install     // still connects to internet to get the dependencies instead of getting the from the local bundle
   node main.js
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong? How do I include the dependencies tarballs into the build, and how do I tell npm install to use them?